# Injection of parameters into signal handlers is deprecated. Use JavaScript functions with formal parameters instead

Tags: qt, qml

I have the following issue.

I'm using QML for my application frontend.

For one of my componentes I use a ListView that uses a custom delegate that contains it's own index (and some other data) in a a variable called vmIndex. Here is the declaration of the list view:

```
                ListView {
                    id: studySelectListView
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    model: studySelectList
                    delegate: VMStudyEntry {
                        width: studySelectBackground.width
                        height: studySelectBackground.height/4
                        onItemSelected: {
                            selectionChanged(vmIndex,true); // LINE WITH WARNING
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Now, when the item is selected I need to call a function called selectionChange and send vmIndex as a parameter to that function.

The VMStudyEntry is this:

```
Item {
    id: vmStudyEntry

    signal itemSelected(int vmIndex);

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            vmStudyEntry.itemSelected(vmIndex);
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: dateRect
        color: vmIsSelected? "#3096ef" : "#ffffff"
        border.color: vmIsSelected? "#144673" : "#3096ef"
        radius: mainWindow.width*0.005
        border.width: mainWindow.width*0.0005
        anchors.fill: parent
        Text {
            font.family: viewHome.gothamR.name
            font.pixelSize: 12*viewHome.vmScale
            text: vmStudyName
            color: vmIsSelected? "#ffffff" : "#000000"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }

}
```

This all worked perfectly on Qt 5.13.2. But I now moved to Qt 6.1.2. The code actually still works, as far as I can see but I'm getting this warning:

```
Parameter "vmIndex" is not declared. Injection of parameters into signal handlers is deprecated. Use JavaScript functions with formal parameters instead.
```

The line that has this warning is identifed above. Can anyone tell me how I can redefine this in order to make this warning go away?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#signal-parameters), you need the following syntax in Qt6:

```
onItemSelected: function(vmIndex) { selectionChanged(vmIndex,true); }
```

Or a more lambda-like options if you fancy:

```
onItemSelected: vmIndex => selectionChanged(vmIndex, true)
```

Comment: Adding the "lambda-like" option to your answer would be useful for the readers. It's called arrow functions : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions
`onItemSelected: vmIndex => selectionChanged(vmIndex, true)`

Comment: You need that in syntax in later version of Qt5 too.

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you! Sorry it took so long for me to actually get a chance to test it out!!

Comment: But what if the signal has no parameter, for example the built-in on<Propname>Changed signals?

For example, the deprecation warning occurs if you put `onContentWidthChanged: { console.log(contentWidth) }` inside a Text { ... }

AFAIK there is no documented parameter passed for the built-in onXXXChanged signals

Comment: It also seems inconsistent:  referencing contentWidth in a signal handler inside a Text{...} causes the warning bug not when referencing implicitWidth

Comment: @jimav that is in line with the original question, right? Because you skip the `function()`, you should do: `onContentWidthChanged: function() { console.log(contentWidth) }` (or even `<text_id>.contentWidth` if doubtfull about the context)

Comment: Okay, but contentWidth is a ref into the closure scope, it is not a *parameter* and the warning talks about 'injecting' parameters and says to use "functions with formal parameters instead".  **So what exactly is being deprecated?**  Is it that bare code (not a function declaration) currently implies function() with closure, but in the future will imply an arrow function without closure?

Comment: ah, now understand you. I don't have the proof at hand, but yes omitting a declaration (be it function or arrow) is what's going to be deprecated. I guess it's a bit of a poor choice of words? Looking at the [code](https://code.woboq.org/qt6/qtdeclarative/src/qml/compiler/qv4codegen.cpp.html#2577) (with several layers of diffusion) I can maybe understand the choice of words