# QML warning context

Tags: qt, qml

The following is my code.

```
Window {
    id : mainWindow
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint  //无边框窗口(去掉title栏)

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent

        property int mouse_x;
        property int mouse_y;

        onPressed: {
            mouse_x = mouse.x;
            mouse_y = mouse.y;
        }

        onMouseXChanged:{
            if(mouse.buttons === Qt.LeftButton)
            {
                mainWindow.x += mouse.x - mouse_x;
            }
        }

        onMouseYChanged: {
            if(mouse.buttons === Qt.LeftButton)
            {
                mainWindow.y += mouse.y - mouse_y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The function can be mplemented normally but there is still some warning text in the console.

```
"Parameter "mouse" is not declared. Injection of parameters into signal handlers is deprecated. Use JavaScript functions with formal parameters instead."
```

Could someone teach me how to solve this problem and teach me why this warning would happened?

Comment: *Signals might have parameters. To access those, you should assign a function to the handler. Both arrow functions and anonymous functions work.* [[1](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#signal-parameters)].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Injection of parameters into signal handlers is deprecated. Use JavaScript functions with formal parameters instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69273910/injection-of-parameters-into-signal-handlers-is-deprecated-use-javascript-funct)

Comment: Also, do not try to manually resize or move the window. Instead, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74166152/11603485).

Comment: The article provides help a lot! Thanks! *3*

Comment: Consider using pressedButtons instead. Thisis because mouseX is a property and its corresponding onMouseXChanged does not have a mouse event property.

Answer (score 2):

From the [MouseArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#details) documentation:

*Many MouseArea signals pass a **mouse** parameter that contains additional information about the mouse event, such as the position, button, and any key modifiers.*

You have to define this **mouse** parameter in your slot to capture it:

```
onMouseXChanged: (mouse) => {
    if(mouse.buttons === Qt.LeftButton)
    {
        mainWindow.x += mouse.x - mouse_x;
    }
}
```

Comment: why must I do this? Could you teach me please? I have searched the answer but I can not understand

Comment: The signal mouseXChanged has a parameter mouse. To use this parameter in your function, you have to capture it like I showed you. In former versions, the mouse parameter was captured automatically, this is why it works without defining it for compatibility (but with a warning, so you notice there is something wrong).

Comment: I am not sure how this can work because mouseX is a property and the corresponding signal onMouseXChanged does not have a mouse parameter in it.

Comment: I have tested it, and indeed the mouse parameter gets injected into the call even the onMouseXChanged signal is not having this parameter. So the above code is working as expected.